# Using asn Angular Smart-Table with complex objects

Tags: json, angularjs, smart-table

I have a data collection that looks like this:

```
[{"disposition":    {"dispositionId":1,"name":"smdnfgn","code":"jkkhkl;hklhlkjhlhkj","description":"DM_Description 1","sortIndex":1,"status":"DM_St 1"}},{"disposition":{"dispositionId":2,"name":"DM_Name 2","code":"DM_Code 2;lkfdg;l'ksadfg","description":"DM_Description 2","sortIndex":2,"status":"DM_St 2"}}, . . .]
```

As you can see the JSON array returned by the backend RESTful service are 'disposition objects with a complex object (dispositionId, name, . . .) for each.

When I pass this collection to a Smart-Table, I get nothing but headers.

However, when I run a method to remove the 'disposition' and turn it into an simplier array, such as:

```
    [{"dispositionId":1,"name":"smdnfgn","code":"jkkhkl;hklhlkjhlhkj","description":"DM_Description 1","sortIndex":1,"status":"DM_St 1"},{"dispositionId":2,"name":"DM_Name 2","code":"DM_Code 2;lkfdg;l'ksadfg","description":"DM_Description 2","sortIndex":2,"status":"DM_St 2"}, . . .]
```

Everything works fine.  Is there a way to get the SMart-Table to recognize the standard JSON configuration without having to edit the data once it's been retrieved?  I feel like I am overlooking something.

My  for looking at the tables are here:

```
<div ng-controller="dispositionSmartCtrl">
<hr>
DispoElements
<smart-table class="table table-striped" table-title="DispoElements"
             config="globalConfig" rows=dispoElements columns="columnCollectionDispo">
</smart-table>
{{dispoElements}}<br /><hr><br />
Disposition RowDispositions
<smart-table class="table table-striped" table-title="RowDispositions"
             config="globalConfig" rows=rowDispositions columns="columnCollectionDispo">
</smart-table>
{{rowDispositions}}
```

The only difference is the Collections being used, one being the complex object, the other being a vanilla array.  I've tried {{}} and also doing 'rowCollections.disposition, and the first causes the page to fail completely, the second gives me a headers only table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this one for myself.  What seemed to be a head-scratch was more of a 'Duh!' moment.  The reason it seemed to complex object was being ignored was two-fold.  First error, and the main one, was that in defining the columns, I failed to include the object reference.  For example I had:

```
{label: 'Name', map: 'name', isEditable: true}
```

instead of:

```
{label: 'Name', map: '***disposition***.name', isEditable: true}
```

The compounding error was that the column being listed didn't correspond to the highest level object, so the smart-table just showed blank rows.  If I hadn't defined the columns at all, I would have seen to Object rather than blank and that might have clued me in quicker.